# how to build a not preload slide show by javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

i would like to make a simple slide show like this:

http://www.businessinsider.com/useful-apps-2013-8#quip-is-a-brand-new-mobile-word-processing-app-quip-is-made-by-facebooks-former-cto-the-app-makes-it-easy-to-create-documents-on-the-go-but-it-still-works-on-your-desktop-too-2

i am new to javascript, may i ask is there any example to build a slide show like above?
it seems the picture will only be loaded from the server side when the user click the previous/next button.

and is there any way to speed us the script as well?

many thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

The two simplest sliders/gallery plugins are fancybox and flexislider. Their are plenty of tutorials and help online to use these.

Comment: thanks for reply. i checked them before.
but what they did is preloaded all the images once the website is loaded 
from my example, actually it seems the image is only loaded once we clicked the button. i thought i will help for the user experience?

thanks again